# Multiple PushNotifications on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

In my application i getting multiple push notifications from the server.Every push notification have different data,and it will go to separate `View`.In `AppDelegate` ,i used to get PushNotifications data but how can i send separate views depends on the different push notifications
when i get.i used to get push notification data also,

```
   - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:
(NSDictionary*)userInfo
```

How can solve this issue ,can you please suggest me.

Comment: Look at the userInfo

Comment: even user info also shows current push notification data but i have multiple push notifications,so every push notification had a separate view

Comment: You'll need to have a server or something to get all of the remote notifications. That method only shows the details for the one that the user interacted with.

Comment: Need to clarify more!

Comment: in my app i get the multiple push notifications ,every notification have a separate view.but how can i goto the separate view when i get the notification @Vizllx

Comment: are you saying , you want to push a view controller depending on the notification type or data?

Comment: yes i need to Push a view from respective data @Vizllx

Comment: did your notification dictionary has this Specific Section information (Name) on which you want to move?

Comment: what is the data you are getting in userinfo?

Comment: in UserInfo i get the data from whatever notification and type of data i need to go different views

Comment: `NSLog` your notification dictionary `userinfo` &  please add in question

Answer (score 1):

userInfo is the dictionary which you will get key values like Message, alert, Sound Info....at below delegate method.

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:
    (NSDictionary*)userInfo
    {

    if([userInfo[@"Message"] isEqualToString:@"View1"])
    {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"] animated:YES];
    }
    else if([userInfo[@"Message"] isEqualToString:@"View2"])
    {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"] animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController3"] animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you..!

Answer (score 0):

A very easy approach:

In your application's `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` check the userinfo dictionary fetch the `keyValue` on which you will decide which `viewController` you have to load. Now put a `if/switch statement` on `keyValue` condition, to check on which `viewController` you have to push. So, depending on the data you can navigate your app to a specific `viewController`.